# php when many users access a php file that writes to textfile is it done simultaneously or one at a time

Tags: php

The hosting package im using wont allow sql and will have to pay more monthly if i want sql and its on a shared server so i cant have a client server set up for my app.

Im making a leaderboard for my first ever app.

so iv decided to do everything using php. the app will launch a link in the browser which will look something like this:

```
....../myAppLeaderBoard.php?opt=submit&?id=5465&name?='myName'&dat=DKGHKDHGKHDKGHSAJDHKJAHGJKHDFGHKJDFHGLKHDFGJHSDJLFGHJKSDHFGKJDSHFKGJHSLKDFHGLSJDHFGLJSHDFGJHSLDFJHGLSDJHFGLSDHJFGLSHDFGHG
```

All those alphabets is because i plan on using my own encrypting technique to prevent a user from cheating and giving themselves a highscore.

when its submitted it will read everything from a textfile  into an array
it will check if the user exists and if they do it will change that record and if they dnt exist it will add a new record,then it will write everything from the array back to the textfile.

Then it will display a success message and show the user on the leaderboard,Now what will happen if say 100000 users each simultaneously submit there scores.

If it reads and writes one record at a time  there wont be a problem but if it does this simultaneously then some records might be deleted by a simultaneous write.

So  is it done simultaneously or one at a time?

Feel free to give suggestions for a better way to do this.

Comment: why can't you buy a better hosting plan if your app is going to be used by 100000  users simultaneously. :P

Comment: I suggest you learn about building *any* kind of web-app before focusing on the kind that can have 100,000 simultaneous visitors.

Comment: If by "encrypting" you actually mean "obfuscating"... that won't work :-) It can be done, but you don't want to do it. (e.g: Homomorphic encryption, or perhaps Proof-of-Work).

Comment: You will need to lock the file when editing, to make sure it's not being overwritten. However, as suggested this is a very bad solution.

Comment: I don't have 100000 users at the moment i was using that as an example. At the moment I have 50+ users and it increases everyday. Also at the moment i cant afford i better hosting plan. earnings from app only come a few months from now. but in time i will upgrade so for now I'll be using sqlite. thanks for all the help everyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File access is simultaneous but you can use [`flock`](http://php.net/flock) to block other handles from accessing the file while you perform your read/write operations. It sounds like the best solution to your problem would be to use PDO and [SQLite](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php) (if available). This way you have the database handle all locking for you but do not need a dedicated database server. SQLite is entirely file based.

If SQLite is not available, you'll want to make use of flock's `LOCK_EX` operation, this will only allow one write stream to access the file at a time, e.g.

```
// create the file handle
$hnd = fopen($destpath, 'ab+');

if ($isReadOperation) {
    // shared lock - simultaneous reads can happen at one time
    flock($hnd, LOCK_SH);

    // perform your read operation
} else {
    // exclusive lock - only one write can occur at a time after all shared locks are released
    flock($hnd, LOCK_EX);

    // perform your read/write operation
}

// release the lock
flock($hnd, LOCK_UN);

// release the file handle
fclose($hnd);
```

Answer (score 1):

File access (and this applies to sqlite databases as well, as they're file-based) is, unfortunately, not supposed to handle many simultaneous read & write operations. Therefore, you *will* run into problems with that.

I'm afraid your only sensible option is buying a hosting plan that offers a real database, e.g. MySQL.